# Twitter Mining using R (twitteR + tm): error using tolower conversion

Tags: r, twitter, tm

I'm having some trouble working with twitter data I extracted using the CRAN Version of the twitteR package. In particular, the tolower conversion from the tm package.

I'm following [this example](http://davetang.org/muse/2013/04/06/using-the-r_twitter-package/)

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
#oauth handshake and so on work fine 
google_8.10<- searchTwitter("#Google", n=1500, cainfo="cacert.pem")
google_8.10_text <- sapply(google_8.10, function(x) x$getText())
google_8.10_text_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(google_8.10_text))
google_8.10_text_corpus <- tm_map(google_8.10_text_corpus, tolower) 
google_8.10_text_corpus <- tm_map(google_8.10_text_corpus, removePunctuation)
google_8.10_text_corpus <- tm_map(google_8.10_text_corpus,            function(x)removeWords(x,stopwords()))
```

The other conversions complete just fine (if tolower isn't run). However the tolower conversion returns:

```
google_8.10_text_corpus <- tm_map(google_8.10_text_corpus, tolower)
    Warnmeldung:
In parallel::mclapply(x, FUN, ...) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
```

I'm having the suspicion that this might be caused by some character in one of the tweets but how can I track the problem down?

edit: 
Indeed, certain characters seem to cause this, eg.:

```
"#Google #TheInternship THE BEST MOVIE EVER @Jeennyy01 @dylanobrien    I love this part \ud83d\ude1c http://t.co/iok5vm83cP"
```

Here the "\ud83d\ude1c" part causes the error. Any idea on how to automatically strip these phrases (this one is: http://www.charbase.com/1f61c-unicode-face-with-stuck-out-tongue-and-winking-eye) from the tweets?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/character.c) `tolower` can give an error:

> ## Support for "bytes" marked encoding
>
> nzchar and nchar(, "bytes") are independent of the encoding.
>
> nchar(, "char") nchar(, "width") give NA (if allowed) or error. substr
>   substr<-  work in bytes
>
> abbreviate chartr make.names strtrim tolower toupper give error.

Here is an example where an error is thrown using an [invalid UTF code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences):

```
tolower("\udc80")
Error in tolower("<ed><U+00B2><U+0080>") : 
  invalid input 'í²€' in 'utf8towcs'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem is easily solved by using the stringi package, which brings its own implementation of a lower case conversion: 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html

Of course, it would be nice if the standard function worked for all characters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to resolve itself when simply running the tm_map(mycorpus, tolower) function again. Then all subsequent functions work correctly. Weird error though...seems like a bug with R.